# Why the return value is not what I expected.?

Tags: android, android-camera

The code fragment is for setting the Camera Parameters as the following:

```
lockRun(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.v("jerikc","applyParameters before width="+getParameters().getPictureSize().width+",height="+getParameters().getPictureSize());
        //preview size changed, zsd changed, camera mode changed, open camera.
        mSettingChecker.applyPreferenceToParameters();
        Log.v("jerikc","applyParameters after width="+getParameters().getPictureSize().width+",height="+getParameters().getPictureSize());
    }
});
```

SettingChecker.java

```
public void applyPreferenceToParameters() {
    Log.v("jerikc","SettingChecker.applyPreferenceToParameters before width="+mContext.getParameters().getPictureSize().width+",height="+mContext.getParameters().getPictureSize());
    ...
    Log.v("jerikc","SettingChecker.applyPreferenceToParameters after width="+mContext.getParameters().getPictureSize().width+",height="+mContext.getParameters().getPictureSize());
}
```

The logs as following:

```
V/jerikc (17866): applyParameters before width=2560,height=android.hardware.Camera$Size@4fde180
V/jerikc (17866): SettingChecker.applyPreferenceToParameters before width=2560,height=android.hardware.Camera$Size@4fde180
V/jerikc (17866): SettingChecker.applyPreferenceToParameters after width=4096,height=android.hardware.Camera$Size@7fc9900
V/jerikc (17866): applyParameters after width=2560,height=android.hardware.Camera$Size@4fde180
```

I add the logs both before and end the call of
**mSettingChecker.applyPreferenceToParameters()** . I also add the logs
before and end inside the method **applyPreferenceToParameters**. The
**getParameters()** will return the **mParameter** object.

Why the values of the width are different(one is 4096, and another is
2560) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the `@4fde180` and `@7fc9900` output at the end of your logged lines, you are using different `Camera.Size` objects.

Your method `applyPreferenceToParameters()` doesn't seem to store the changed value at the location you are expecting in the other method/class.